# Problema con guardado de rango de datos en PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un sitio sobre reservas de complejos deportivos, los cuales tienen un cierto número de canchas asociadas. En el tengo unos checkbox que se generan automaticamente segun el numero de canchas asociadas que tenga el complejo, un rango de fechas (2 `<input>`) y 2 `<select>` con horarios que también corresponden a un rango. Todo esto diseñado en Laravel 5.5.40 con PHP.

Antes de que se envíen los datos del formulario me gustaría establecer una validación; de momento explico como funciona el sitio.

Lo primero se selecciona un complejo deportivo, luego se selecciona las canchas asociadas que tiene, luego se escoge un rango de fechas y por último se escogen los horarios que va a tener.

Como única validación que me gustaría establecer, es que según las canchas escogidas más el rango de fechas escogidas, y más los horarios, se generen múltiples registros, para cada cancha, es decir, **por ejemplo:**

El siguiente complejo deportivo de nombre ***'SuperSporting'*** tiene **2** canchas asociadas, una de tenis y otra de football. Para este complejo deportivo se seleccionó un rango de fechas desde el **`01-12-2018`** hasta el **`31-12-2018.`** Y un rango de horario desde las **08:00** AM hasta las **23:00** PM. Al momento de guardar me debería generar en la base de datos lo siguiente.

- Para los registros nuevos, cada uno tendrán una fecha definida que depende obligatoriamente del rango de fechas seleccionadas, por ejemplo:

  - Uno tendrá como fecha **`2018-12-01`**, otro tendrá **`2018-12-02`**, el siguiente tendrá **`2018-12-03`** y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al último día escogido del rango de fechas.
  - Luego se debería guardar de *hora en hora* partiendo desde las **`8:00`** y finalizando en **`23:00`** (Para este caso).

Es decir; un registro tendrá como fecha inicial, el día inicial escogido más el horario inicial escogido, este irá en aumento de hora en hora para cada registro nuevo hasta finalizar el día, y una vez completado seguirá con el siguiente día, de hora en hora, hasta finalizar con la última fecha escogida del rango.

Quedando finalmente de esta manera:

_Cambiaremos un poco el ejemplo, ahora se seleccionó un rango de fechas desde el **`01-12-2018`** hasta el **`01-12-2018`;** el horario se mantiene **`desde las 08:00 hasta las 23:00 Hrs,`** y la cancha seleccionada es la de fútbol, es el mismo dia; pero lo siguiente es para que se entienda la manera en que se me deberían generar los horarios:

```
`MI TABLA HORARIO`

id|horario_inicio     |horario_fin        |estado_horario_id|cancha_id
 1|2018-12-01 08:00:00|2018-12-01 09:00:00|                1|        2
 2|2018-12-01 09:00:00|2018-12-01 10:00:00|                1|        2
 3|2018-12-01 10:00:00|2018-12-01 11:00:00|                1|        2
 4|2018-12-01 11:00:00|2018-12-01 12:00:00|                1|        2
 5|2018-12-01 12:00:00|2018-12-01 13:00:00|                1|        2
 6|2018-12-01 13:00:00|2018-12-01 14:00:00|                1|        2
 7|2018-12-01 14:00:00|2018-12-01 15:00:00|                1|        2
 8|2018-12-01 15:00:00|2018-12-01 16:00:00|                1|        2   
 9|2018-12-01 16:00:00|2018-12-01 17:00:00|                1|        2
10|2018-12-01 17:00:00|2018-12-01 18:00:00|                1|        2
11|2018-12-01 18:00:00|2018-12-01 19:00:00|                1|        2
12|2018-12-01 19:00:00|2018-12-01 20:00:00|                1|        2
13|2018-12-01 20:00:00|2018-12-01 21:00:00|                1|        2
14|2018-12-01 21:00:00|2018-12-01 22:00:00|                1|        2
15|2018-12-01 22:00:00|2018-12-01 23:00:00|                1|        2
```

Eso corresponde a un día, si el rango hubiese sido por ejemplo hasta el 02 de diciembre, el registro hubiese continuado hasta finalizar el siguiente día.

Para entender un poco mejor sobre la estructura de esto, si se viera como un diagrama de flujo, sobre **cómo debería ser el *orden*** al momento de generar los nuevos registros; sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
Inicio
    -> CANCHA 1 (SELECCIONA)
       * RANGO FECHAS (SELECCIONA Y APLICA A TODAS LAS CANCHAS SELECCIONADAS)
         # POR DIA
           ° HORARIOS (SE GENERAN)

    -> CANCHA 2 (SELECCIONA)
       * RANGO FECHAS
         # POR DIA
           ° HORARIOS

    -> CANCHA 3 (SELECCIONA)
       * RANGO FECHAS
         # POR DIA             
           ° HORARIOS

    /*EN CASO DE SER MAYOR O MENOR LA CANTIDAD DE CANCHAS ASOCIADAS y 
    SELECCIONADAS EL PROCESO CONTINUA HASTA FINALIZAR CON LA ÚLTIMA O LA 
    ÚNICA CANCHA SELECCIONADA MAS EL RANGO DE FECHAS Y HORARIOS ELEGIDOS*/

-> GUARDAR
FIN
```

Pero como expliqué al comienzo no me genera de esa manera el guardado de registros múltiple. Al momento de enviar los datos no me toma el rango de fecha ni de horarios, los guarda como registros independientes, pero si toma los checkbox seleccionados.

Esta imagen lo explica de mejor manera, seleccioné 2 checkbox para un complejo deportivo, un rango de fechas desde el 01-01-2019 hasta el 05-01-2019 y un rango de horario desde las 08:00 hasta las 23:00 Hrs, pero como expliqué no toma el rango de fechas y horarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería generarse para cada checkbox, y cada día del rango escogidos todos los horarios desde las 08:00 hasta las 23:00 Hrs de hora en hora 08-09, 09-10, etc.

De momento esto tengo en mi controlador. Que me genera los nuevos registros:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    try {

        foreach($request->horario as $id_horario=>$row){    
            foreach($row['check'] as $check){ 

                $horarios = new HorariosNew();
                $horarios->hora_inicio = $row['desde'].' '.$row['sel']; 
                $horarios->hora_fin = $row['hasta'].' '.$row['sel2'];
                $horarios->estado_horario_id = $row['estado_horario_id']; 
                $horarios->cancha_id = $check; 
                $horarios->save(); 
            }
        }   
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

        Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
        return redirect()->route('horarios.store');
      }

        Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
        return redirect()->route('horarios.store');
}
```

Y este es el formulario, esta vez lo pondré dentro de un snippet solo porque es algo extenso.

```js
/*FUNCION QUE VALIDA LA SELECCION DE FECHAS, COMO POR EJEMPLO QUE NO PUEDE SER MENOR 
QUE LA ACTUAL, Y QUE NO PUEDE SER MENOR QUE LA PRIMERA FECHA ESCOGIDA*/
function ValidaFecha(e){

        var fecha1 = new Date(desde.value);
        var fecha2 = new Date(hasta.value);
        
        var hoy = new Date();
        var Anio = hoy.getFullYear();

        var months = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"];
        
        var days = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
        
        var Mes = months[hoy.getMonth()];
        var Dia = days[hoy.getDate()];
        var dia_n = hoy.getDate();
        
        
        /*if(fecha1 <= hoy){

            $('#desde').focus();

              $.alert({
                title: ''+'<nav style=" background: #478573; color:white; width: 20cm; height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top: 2.5mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;¡Atencion!</nav>',
                content: ''+'<p style="color:black;font-weight: 500; text-align: justify !important; font-size: 12pt;" >La fecha de escogida no puede ser menor que la fecha actual.</p><p style="font-size: 10pt; color: black; font-weight: 600; text-align: justify;">Actualmente estamos a: <br> '+Dia+' '+dia_n+' '+'de'+' '+Mes+' '+'del'+' '+Anio+'</p>',

            });
                
            return false;

        }else */if (fecha2 < fecha1) {

            $('#hasta').focus();

              $.alert({
                title: ''+'<nav style=" background: #478573; color:white; width: 15cm; height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top: 2.5mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;¡Atencion!</nav>',
                content: ''+' <p style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >La fecha de termino no puede ser menor que la fecha inicial.</p>',

            });
                
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*FUNCION QUE VALIDA QUE SE SELECCIONE AL MENOS UN CHECKBOX*/
        
        $('form').submit(function(e){
    
        // si la cantidad de checkboxes "chequeados" es cero,
        // entonces se evita que se envíe el formulario y se
        // muestra una alerta al usuario
        

        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0) {
                
                e.preventDefault();
        
                $('#top_page').focus();
            
                $('#img_warning').fadeIn(1000);
            
                $.alert({
                title: ''+'<nav style=" background: #478573; color:white; width: 15cm; height: 10mm; margin-top: -5mm; margin-left: -5mm; padding-top: 2.5mm;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¡Atencion!</nav>',
                content: ''+' <label style= "color: black; font-weight: 500;" >Debe seleccionar al menos un elemento de la lista.</label>',
                });       
            }    
        });

    function MuestraCanchas(event){  /*OK*/
        
        var target = $(event.target);
        var value = target.val();

        $('.DivCheckCanchas').hide();
        $('.DivCanchas').hide();
        $('#img_warning').hide();

        $('[data-complejo="'+value+'"]').closest('.DivCanchas').show().css({"margin-bottom":"10px"});
        $('[data-complejo="'+value+'"]').closest('.DivCheckCanchas').show().css({"margin-bottom":"10px"});;
            
    }


    /*OK*/
    function numeros(e){
            
        var tecla = e.keyCode;

        if (tecla==8 || tecla==9 || tecla==13){
            return true;
        }
        
        var patron =/[1-2]/;
        var tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(tecla_final);
    }
```

```html
@section('content')
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title" style="color: black;">Agregar un nuevo Horario</h4>
            <input type="text" id="top_page" readonly="readonly">
            <h6 class="card-subtitle" style="color: grey; position: relative; bottom: 7mm;"> Debe rellenar los campos solicitados</h6>


            {!! Form::open(['route'=> 'horarios.store','method'=> 'POST' ,'class'=>"form-material m-t-40",'name'=>'horario', 'id'=>'horario_id', 'files' => true] ) !!}

            <div style="position: relative; bottom: 1cm;">
                    
                <label style="color: black;">Complejos</label>
                <br>
                <label style="color: grey;">Seleccione un complejo</label>
                <br>
                
                <select id="complejos" required="required" onchange="MuestraCanchas(event)">
                        
                    <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                    <option value="{{$complejo->id}}">{{$complejo->nombre}}</option>   
                </select>

                <br><br>

                <div class="DivCheckCanchas" id="DivCheckCanchas">
                        
                    <label style="color: black;" id="label_check">*&nbsp;Seleccione una cancha o campo</label>
                        
                    <div id="img_warning">
                        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148768.svg" class="img_warning" width="30">
                    </div>
                        
                    <h6 style="color: grey;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tambien puede seleccionar más de una opción.</h6>
                            
                    <br>
                    @foreach($campos as $campos)
                    <div id="DivCanchas" class="DivCanchas" style="width: 22%;">
                        
                        <input type="checkbox" data-complejo="{{$campos->complejo_id}}" id="{{$campos->nombre}}" value="{{$campos->id}}" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][check][]" >
                                    
                        <label id="LabelCanchas" style="color: grey; margin-left: 2mm;" for="{{$campos->nombre}}">{{$campos->nombre}}</label>

                        <br>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach                      
                </div>
                        
                <br>
                <label style="color: black;">FECHAS</label>
                    
                <br><br>
                <div class="input-daterange input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">DESDE</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][desde]"  id="desde" required="required" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-info b-0 text-white">HASTA</span>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][hasta]" id="hasta" required="required"/>
                </div>
                    
                <br><br>
                <label style="color: black;">HORARIO DE INICIO</label>
                <label style="color: black; position: relative; left: 10cm;">HORARIO DE TERMINO</label>
                <br>
                <label style="color: grey;">Seleccione una hora</label>
                <label style="position: relative; left: 94.5mm; color: grey;">Seleccione una hora</label>
                <br>


                <select name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][sel]" id="options1" required="required" class="option">
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                    <option value="08:00:00">08:00:00</option>
                    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                    <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                    <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                    <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                    <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                    <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                    <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                </select>
                
                <select name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][sel2]" id="options2" required="required" class="option2">
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                    <option value="09:00:00">09:00:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00:00">10:00:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00:00">11:00:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00:00">12:00:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00:00">13:00:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00:00">14:00:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00:00">15:00:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00:00">16:00:00</option>
                    <option value="17:00:00">17:00:00</option>
                    <option value="18:00:00">18:00:00</option>
                    <option value="19:00:00">19:00:00</option>
                    <option value="20:00:00">20:00:00</option>
                    <option value="21:00:00">21:00:00</option>
                    <option value="22:00:00">22:00:00</option>
                    <option value="23:00:00">23:00:00</option>
                </select>
                
                <br><br><br>
                <label style="color: black;">Estado</label>
                <br>
                        
                <input type="text" value="2" class="form-control form-control-line" style="width: 10%;" onkeypress="return numeros(event)" maxlength="1" required="required" name="horario[{{$last_horario->id}}][estado_horario_id]">
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" id="btn-success" value="REGISTRAR" onclick="return ValidaFecha(event)">

                <a href="{{route('horarios.show', [" id, nombre, direccion, comuna, telefono" => $complejo-> id, 'nombre', 'direccion', 'comuna', 'telefono'])}}"">
                    <input type="button"  id="btn-cancelar" value="CANCELAR">
                </a>
                <br><br>
            </div>
               
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Añado además una captura del formulario, que diseñe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que se entienda, ¿Como lo podría solucionar?

Comment: ¿qué datos se ven en `$request->all()`? a ver si logro entender mejor

Comment: Esto se obtiene. `array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "UqraxJ71q4n2yxb0RiUabM7bVIFkNhaN0xS08zdO"
  "horario" => array:1 [▼
    869 => array:6 [▼
      "check" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "2"
      ]
      "desde" => "2018-12-08"
      "hasta" => "2018-12-08"
      "sel" => "10:00:00"
      "sel2" => "23:00:00"
      "estado_horario_id" => "1"
    ]
  ]
]`

Comment: Lo que necesito ver es los datos enviados desde el formulario que generan los dos registros de la base de datos que se muestran en la captura de pantalla.

Comment: Estimado actualice la pregunta con lo que necesitaba. Quedo atento.

Comment: Creo que de nuevo no fue clara mi solicitud... yo veo dos registros en la base de datos, uno con el id 89 y otro con el 90, en ambos la fecha de inicio es 2019-01-01 y la fecha final es 2019-01-05. Lo que yo quiero ver es cuáles fueron los datos ingresados que generaron ESOS 2 registros que ya están en la base de datos.

Comment: Volví a actualizar la pregunta, si se fija bien en las FECHAS están las mismas que aparecen en la base de datos, _estas_ más los horarios; y las canchas seleccionadas se envían, estos datos son recibidos por el controlador que publiqué en la pregunta. Espero que se haya entendido bien. Gracias.

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo como son las mismas fechas, en el formulario dice: 01-12-2018 y 05-12-2018, y en la base de datos dice 2019-01-01 y 2019-01-05. Realmente no entiendo en qué parte son iguales, tal y como ud. lo dice, siendo así espero que lo pueda solucionar pronto, porque yo no entendí.

Comment: Si es cierto disculpe, una vez más actualice la pregunta; pero el mecanismo de como debería funcionar es ese, primero se selecciona un complejo deportivo, luego las canchas que tenga seleccionadas, luego un rango de fecha y de horario y por ultimo se envían los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo el sentido de guardar todas esas fechas y horarios en la base de datos, lo único que se consigue es saturar las tablas con información basura. Imaginate que quieran reservar desde el **12-12-2018** al **13-01-2019** de **08:00** a **16:00**, con solo 5 iteraciones tendriamos 45 registros en la base de datos. Con las 33 que se generan del **12-12-2018** al **13-01-2019** habrá más de 290 registros, desde mi punto de vista esto es un desperdicio de recursos. De todas formas si quieres hacer esto te dejo el codigo que puede ayudarte.

```
function getDatesBetween($startDate, $endDate, $startTime, $endTime) {
    $period = Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate); // Creamos un objeto "periodo" propio de Carbon
    $dates = $times = []; // variables para almacenar las fechas y los horarios
    $tstart = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $startTime); // creamos una instancia de carbon para la hora de inicio
    $tend = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $endTime); // y otra instancia para la hora de finalización

    while ($tstart <= $tend) { // mientras la hora de inicio sea menor o igual a la hora de finalización
        $times[] = $tstart->format("H:i:s"); // agregamos esa hora al array de los horarios
        $tstart->addHour(); // aumentamos en 1 hora 
    }

    foreach ($period as $date) { // recorremos todas las fechas generadas en el periodo
        foreach ($times as $time) { // así como los horarios generados en el while anterior
            $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $time; // y los concatenamos y guardamos en el array de las fechas
        }
    }

    return $dates; // creo que esto no hace falta explicarlo
}

dd(getDatesBetween("2018-12-12", "2019-01-13", "08:00:00", "16:00:00")); // ejemplo de uso
```

Esto dará como resultado lo siguiente:

```
array:297 [▼
  0 => "2018-12-12 08:00:00"
  1 => "2018-12-12 09:00:00"
  2 => "2018-12-12 10:00:00"
  3 => "2018-12-12 11:00:00"
  4 => "2018-12-12 12:00:00"
  5 => "2018-12-12 13:00:00"
  6 => "2018-12-12 14:00:00"
  7 => "2018-12-12 15:00:00"
  8 => "2018-12-12 16:00:00"
  9 => "2018-12-13 08:00:00"
  10 => "2018-12-13 09:00:00"
  11 => "2018-12-13 10:00:00"
  12 => "2018-12-13 11:00:00"
  13 => "2018-12-13 12:00:00"
  14 => "2018-12-13 13:00:00"
  15 => "2018-12-13 14:00:00"
  16 => "2018-12-13 15:00:00"
  17 => "2018-12-13 16:00:00"
  18 => "2018-12-14 08:00:00"
  19 => "2018-12-14 09:00:00"
  20 => "2018-12-14 10:00:00"
  21 => "2018-12-14 11:00:00"
  22 => "2018-12-14 12:00:00"
  23 => "2018-12-14 13:00:00"
  24 => "2018-12-14 14:00:00"
  25 => "2018-12-14 15:00:00"
  26 => "2018-12-14 16:00:00"
  27 => "2018-12-15 08:00:00"
  28 => "2018-12-15 09:00:00"
  29 => "2018-12-15 10:00:00"
  30 => "2018-12-15 11:00:00"
  31 => "2018-12-15 12:00:00"
  32 => "2018-12-15 13:00:00"
  33 => "2018-12-15 14:00:00"
  34 => "2018-12-15 15:00:00"
  35 => "2018-12-15 16:00:00"
  36 => "2018-12-16 08:00:00"
  37 => "2018-12-16 09:00:00"
  38 => "2018-12-16 10:00:00"
  39 => "2018-12-16 11:00:00"
  40 => "2018-12-16 12:00:00"
  41 => "2018-12-16 13:00:00"
  42 => "2018-12-16 14:00:00"
  43 => "2018-12-16 15:00:00"
  44 => "2018-12-16 16:00:00"
  45 => "2018-12-17 08:00:00"
  46 => "2018-12-17 09:00:00"
  47 => "2018-12-17 10:00:00"
  48 => "2018-12-17 11:00:00"
  49 => "2018-12-17 12:00:00"
  50 => "2018-12-17 13:00:00"
  51 => "2018-12-17 14:00:00"
  52 => "2018-12-17 15:00:00"
  53 => "2018-12-17 16:00:00"
  54 => "2018-12-18 08:00:00"
  55 => "2018-12-18 09:00:00"
  56 => "2018-12-18 10:00:00"
  57 => "2018-12-18 11:00:00"
  58 => "2018-12-18 12:00:00"
  59 => "2018-12-18 13:00:00"
  60 => "2018-12-18 14:00:00"
  61 => "2018-12-18 15:00:00"
  62 => "2018-12-18 16:00:00"
  63 => "2018-12-19 08:00:00"
  64 => "2018-12-19 09:00:00"
  65 => "2018-12-19 10:00:00"
  66 => "2018-12-19 11:00:00"
  67 => "2018-12-19 12:00:00"
  68 => "2018-12-19 13:00:00"
  69 => "2018-12-19 14:00:00"
  70 => "2018-12-19 15:00:00"
  71 => "2018-12-19 16:00:00"
  72 => "2018-12-20 08:00:00"
  73 => "2018-12-20 09:00:00"
  74 => "2018-12-20 10:00:00"
  75 => "2018-12-20 11:00:00"
  76 => "2018-12-20 12:00:00"
  77 => "2018-12-20 13:00:00"
  78 => "2018-12-20 14:00:00"
  79 => "2018-12-20 15:00:00"
  80 => "2018-12-20 16:00:00"
  81 => "2018-12-21 08:00:00"
  82 => "2018-12-21 09:00:00"
  83 => "2018-12-21 10:00:00"
  84 => "2018-12-21 11:00:00"
  85 => "2018-12-21 12:00:00"
  86 => "2018-12-21 13:00:00"
  87 => "2018-12-21 14:00:00"
  88 => "2018-12-21 15:00:00"
  89 => "2018-12-21 16:00:00"
  90 => "2018-12-22 08:00:00"
  91 => "2018-12-22 09:00:00"
  92 => "2018-12-22 10:00:00"
  93 => "2018-12-22 11:00:00"
  94 => "2018-12-22 12:00:00"
  95 => "2018-12-22 13:00:00"
  96 => "2018-12-22 14:00:00"
  97 => "2018-12-22 15:00:00"
  98 => "2018-12-22 16:00:00"
  99 => "2018-12-23 08:00:00"
  100 => "2018-12-23 09:00:00"
  101 => "2018-12-23 10:00:00"
  102 => "2018-12-23 11:00:00"
  103 => "2018-12-23 12:00:00"
  104 => "2018-12-23 13:00:00"
  105 => "2018-12-23 14:00:00"
  106 => "2018-12-23 15:00:00"
  107 => "2018-12-23 16:00:00"
  108 => "2018-12-24 08:00:00"
  109 => "2018-12-24 09:00:00"
  110 => "2018-12-24 10:00:00"
  111 => "2018-12-24 11:00:00"
  112 => "2018-12-24 12:00:00"
  113 => "2018-12-24 13:00:00"
  114 => "2018-12-24 14:00:00"
  115 => "2018-12-24 15:00:00"
  116 => "2018-12-24 16:00:00"
  117 => "2018-12-25 08:00:00"
  118 => "2018-12-25 09:00:00"
  119 => "2018-12-25 10:00:00"
  120 => "2018-12-25 11:00:00"
  121 => "2018-12-25 12:00:00"
  122 => "2018-12-25 13:00:00"
  123 => "2018-12-25 14:00:00"
  124 => "2018-12-25 15:00:00"
  125 => "2018-12-25 16:00:00"
  126 => "2018-12-26 08:00:00"
  127 => "2018-12-26 09:00:00"
  128 => "2018-12-26 10:00:00"
  129 => "2018-12-26 11:00:00"
  130 => "2018-12-26 12:00:00"
  131 => "2018-12-26 13:00:00"
  132 => "2018-12-26 14:00:00"
  133 => "2018-12-26 15:00:00"
  134 => "2018-12-26 16:00:00"
  135 => "2018-12-27 08:00:00"
  136 => "2018-12-27 09:00:00"
  137 => "2018-12-27 10:00:00"
  138 => "2018-12-27 11:00:00"
  139 => "2018-12-27 12:00:00"
  140 => "2018-12-27 13:00:00"
  141 => "2018-12-27 14:00:00"
  142 => "2018-12-27 15:00:00"
  143 => "2018-12-27 16:00:00"
  144 => "2018-12-28 08:00:00"
  145 => "2018-12-28 09:00:00"
  146 => "2018-12-28 10:00:00"
  147 => "2018-12-28 11:00:00"
  148 => "2018-12-28 12:00:00"
  149 => "2018-12-28 13:00:00"
  150 => "2018-12-28 14:00:00"
  151 => "2018-12-28 15:00:00"
  152 => "2018-12-28 16:00:00"
  153 => "2018-12-29 08:00:00"
  154 => "2018-12-29 09:00:00"
  155 => "2018-12-29 10:00:00"
  156 => "2018-12-29 11:00:00"
  157 => "2018-12-29 12:00:00"
  158 => "2018-12-29 13:00:00"
  159 => "2018-12-29 14:00:00"
  160 => "2018-12-29 15:00:00"
  161 => "2018-12-29 16:00:00"
  162 => "2018-12-30 08:00:00"
  163 => "2018-12-30 09:00:00"
  164 => "2018-12-30 10:00:00"
  165 => "2018-12-30 11:00:00"
  166 => "2018-12-30 12:00:00"
  167 => "2018-12-30 13:00:00"
  168 => "2018-12-30 14:00:00"
  169 => "2018-12-30 15:00:00"
  170 => "2018-12-30 16:00:00"
  171 => "2018-12-31 08:00:00"
  172 => "2018-12-31 09:00:00"
  173 => "2018-12-31 10:00:00"
  174 => "2018-12-31 11:00:00"
  175 => "2018-12-31 12:00:00"
  176 => "2018-12-31 13:00:00"
  177 => "2018-12-31 14:00:00"
  178 => "2018-12-31 15:00:00"
  179 => "2018-12-31 16:00:00"
  180 => "2019-01-01 08:00:00"
  181 => "2019-01-01 09:00:00"
  182 => "2019-01-01 10:00:00"
  183 => "2019-01-01 11:00:00"
  184 => "2019-01-01 12:00:00"
  185 => "2019-01-01 13:00:00"
  186 => "2019-01-01 14:00:00"
  187 => "2019-01-01 15:00:00"
  188 => "2019-01-01 16:00:00"
  189 => "2019-01-02 08:00:00"
  190 => "2019-01-02 09:00:00"
  191 => "2019-01-02 10:00:00"
  192 => "2019-01-02 11:00:00"
  193 => "2019-01-02 12:00:00"
  194 => "2019-01-02 13:00:00"
  195 => "2019-01-02 14:00:00"
  196 => "2019-01-02 15:00:00"
  197 => "2019-01-02 16:00:00"
  198 => "2019-01-03 08:00:00"
  199 => "2019-01-03 09:00:00"
  200 => "2019-01-03 10:00:00"
  201 => "2019-01-03 11:00:00"
  202 => "2019-01-03 12:00:00"
  203 => "2019-01-03 13:00:00"
  204 => "2019-01-03 14:00:00"
  205 => "2019-01-03 15:00:00"
  206 => "2019-01-03 16:00:00"
  207 => "2019-01-04 08:00:00"
  208 => "2019-01-04 09:00:00"
  209 => "2019-01-04 10:00:00"
  210 => "2019-01-04 11:00:00"
  211 => "2019-01-04 12:00:00"
  212 => "2019-01-04 13:00:00"
  213 => "2019-01-04 14:00:00"
  214 => "2019-01-04 15:00:00"
  215 => "2019-01-04 16:00:00"
  216 => "2019-01-05 08:00:00"
  217 => "2019-01-05 09:00:00"
  218 => "2019-01-05 10:00:00"
  219 => "2019-01-05 11:00:00"
  220 => "2019-01-05 12:00:00"
  221 => "2019-01-05 13:00:00"
  222 => "2019-01-05 14:00:00"
  223 => "2019-01-05 15:00:00"
  224 => "2019-01-05 16:00:00"
  225 => "2019-01-06 08:00:00"
  226 => "2019-01-06 09:00:00"
  227 => "2019-01-06 10:00:00"
  228 => "2019-01-06 11:00:00"
  229 => "2019-01-06 12:00:00"
  230 => "2019-01-06 13:00:00"
  231 => "2019-01-06 14:00:00"
  232 => "2019-01-06 15:00:00"
  233 => "2019-01-06 16:00:00"
  234 => "2019-01-07 08:00:00"
  235 => "2019-01-07 09:00:00"
  236 => "2019-01-07 10:00:00"
  237 => "2019-01-07 11:00:00"
  238 => "2019-01-07 12:00:00"
  239 => "2019-01-07 13:00:00"
  240 => "2019-01-07 14:00:00"
  241 => "2019-01-07 15:00:00"
  242 => "2019-01-07 16:00:00"
  243 => "2019-01-08 08:00:00"
  244 => "2019-01-08 09:00:00"
  245 => "2019-01-08 10:00:00"
  246 => "2019-01-08 11:00:00"
  247 => "2019-01-08 12:00:00"
  248 => "2019-01-08 13:00:00"
  249 => "2019-01-08 14:00:00"
  250 => "2019-01-08 15:00:00"
  251 => "2019-01-08 16:00:00"
  252 => "2019-01-09 08:00:00"
  253 => "2019-01-09 09:00:00"
  254 => "2019-01-09 10:00:00"
  255 => "2019-01-09 11:00:00"
  256 => "2019-01-09 12:00:00"
  257 => "2019-01-09 13:00:00"
  258 => "2019-01-09 14:00:00"
  259 => "2019-01-09 15:00:00"
  260 => "2019-01-09 16:00:00"
  261 => "2019-01-10 08:00:00"
  262 => "2019-01-10 09:00:00"
  263 => "2019-01-10 10:00:00"
  264 => "2019-01-10 11:00:00"
  265 => "2019-01-10 12:00:00"
  266 => "2019-01-10 13:00:00"
  267 => "2019-01-10 14:00:00"
  268 => "2019-01-10 15:00:00"
  269 => "2019-01-10 16:00:00"
  270 => "2019-01-11 08:00:00"
  271 => "2019-01-11 09:00:00"
  272 => "2019-01-11 10:00:00"
  273 => "2019-01-11 11:00:00"
  274 => "2019-01-11 12:00:00"
  275 => "2019-01-11 13:00:00"
  276 => "2019-01-11 14:00:00"
  277 => "2019-01-11 15:00:00"
  278 => "2019-01-11 16:00:00"
  279 => "2019-01-12 08:00:00"
  280 => "2019-01-12 09:00:00"
  281 => "2019-01-12 10:00:00"
  282 => "2019-01-12 11:00:00"
  283 => "2019-01-12 12:00:00"
  284 => "2019-01-12 13:00:00"
  285 => "2019-01-12 14:00:00"
  286 => "2019-01-12 15:00:00"
  287 => "2019-01-12 16:00:00"
  288 => "2019-01-13 08:00:00"
  289 => "2019-01-13 09:00:00"
  290 => "2019-01-13 10:00:00"
  291 => "2019-01-13 11:00:00"
  292 => "2019-01-13 12:00:00"
  293 => "2019-01-13 13:00:00"
  294 => "2019-01-13 14:00:00"
  295 => "2019-01-13 15:00:00"
  296 => "2019-01-13 16:00:00"
]
```

Ya queda de ti guardar cada uno de estos registros en la DB. Aunque vuelvo a repetir, es un desperdicio de recursos.

Saludos!

Comment: `Carbon\CarbonPeriod` Obtengo un error que dice que no encuentra esa clase. Será que necesito actualizar Carbon? Uso Laravel 5.5.4

Comment: Más bién necesitas actualizar Laravel, creo que CarbonPeriod se agregó en la 5.6. Si sigues trabajando con esa versión de Laravel mi respuesta no te será de utilidad. ¿La respuesta de @Shaz te sirvio o te dio el mismo error?

Comment: El código funciona bien, luego de ir probando y probando me di cuenta,que guarda las fechas pero no las separa, es decir, me guarda todas las fechas escogidas en un periodo dentro de 1 solo campo de mi tabla, en vez de dividir las fechas en 2 campos distintos. Si se fija bien debería quedar como en el ejemplo que puse en la pregunta (en rojo). Lo digo porque para guardar las fechas hago esto: `$horarios = new HorariosNew();` `$horarios->fecha_inicio = $dates;`  `$horarios->fecha_fin = $dates.` O puede ser que estoy guardando mal la variable $dates.

Answer (score 1):

No sé qué versión de Laravel esté utilizando, pero lo puede solucionar con las herramientas de Carbon. En las versiones recientes de Laravel, los campos definidos como fechas en los modelos son «convertidos» automáticamente a instancias de Carbon. Esto lo comento con fines de futuras mejoras en términos de compatibilidad y escalabilidad del proyecto.

Teniendo en cuenta que hay una fecha y hora de inicio y fin, podría iterar haciendo comparaciones, una idea rápida sería:

```
protected function generateTimeSlots($startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime)
{
    $timeSlots = [];
    $currentStart = $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', "$startDate $startTime");
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', "$endDate $endTime");

    $currentEndOfDay = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', "$startDate $endTime");

   // tenemos dos variables "dinámicas" que van determinando la hora inicial del slot actual y la hora final del "día actual" según el rango 

    while ($currentStart < $end) {
        $currentEnd = $currentStart->addHour();

        $timeSlots[] = ['start' => $currentStart, 'end' => $currentEnd];

        if ($currentEnd >= $currentEndOfDay) {
            $currentStart = $start->addDay();
            $currentEnd = $currentEndOfDay->addDay();
        }
    }

    return $timeSlots;
}
```

NOTA: este código no está probado, por lo cual pueden haber errores al momento de implementarlo, es más una idea de como generar los slots de tiempo y almacenarlos en un array.

Comment: Tienes razón el código no funciona como debe ser, pero entiendo un poco la idea.

Comment: El objetivo es guiar y ya ud. puede completar y mejorar la idea, el código lo escribí rápidamente desde el teléfono, por lo cual me era casi imposible probarlo.

Comment: Si la respuesta sirvió y/o ayudó a resolver el problema, puede marcarla como aceptada.